# What kind of apparel did Carthaginians wear?

Tags: clothing, carthage

Did Carthaginians wear togas like the Romans did? Did they wear laurels? What kind of other clothing might they have worn? (If you're looking for a specific time period - around the beginning of the [Second Punic War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Punic_War).)

Comment: Yes, I believe they did. I am reading a similar question here: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12308/roman-era-clothing-egypt-carthage